# Prevent Hydra from URL encoding spaces

Tags: hydra

I'm having some problems with JSON requests in Hydra. I have a wordlist which consists of lots of lines; each with 2 words separated by a space. I run Hydra using the following command:

```
sudo hydra -l "" -P wordlist.txt example.com http-post-form "/api/:{\"password\"\:\"^PASS^\"}:\"success\"\:false}:H=Accept: */*:H=Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br:H=Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9:H=Content-Type: application/json"
```

When looking at the request body in Wireshark, it appears like this:

```
{"password":"example%20words"}
```

When what I would hope to see is:

```
{"password":"example words"}
```

I have looked around for a little bit, and can't seem to find a way to disable this. Hope someone can help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up "solving" this by simply commenting out parts of the *html_encode* function in the *hydra-http-form.c* file.